# Providing test data in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

How can I run the same test against a lot of different data?

I want to be reported of **all** failures.

For example:

```
def isEven(number):
    return True # Quite buggy implementation

data = [
    (2, True),
    (3, False),
    (4, True),
    (5, False),
]

class MyTest:
   def evenTest(self, num, expected):
       self.assertEquals(expected, isEven(num))
```

I have found solution which raises error on first failure only:
*[PHPUnit style dataProvider in Python unit test](http://melp.nl/2011/02/phpunit-style-dataprovider-in-python-unit-test/)*

How can I run a test to be reported of all failures?

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Python's unittest and dynamic creation of test cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193909)*. Which is itself a duplicate of *[How do you generate dynamic (parameterized) unit tests in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899)*. Why and why not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be using `py.test`. I think the unittest module was blindly copied from JUnit. Anyway, you can hack your way like this:

```
import unittest

data = [
    (2, True),
    (3, False),
    (4, True),
    (5, False)]

# This should be imported from a separate module.
def isEven(number):
    return True # Quite buggy implementation

def create_test_func(num, expected):
    def _test_func(self):
        self.assertEqual(expected, isEven(num))
    return _test_func

class TestIsEven(unittest.TestCase):

    pass

# pyunit isn't Pythonic enough. Use py.test instead
# till then we rely on such hackery
import new
for i, (num, expected) in enumerate(data):
    setattr(TestIsEven, 'test_data_%d'%i, create_test_func(num, expected))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

And the output is:

```
.F.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_data_1 (__main__.TestIsEven)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled-1.py", line 15, in _test_func
    self.assertEqual(expected, isEven(num))
AssertionError: False != True

======================================================================
FAIL: test_data_3 (__main__.TestIsEven)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled-1.py", line 15, in _test_func
    self.assertEqual(expected, isEven(num))
AssertionError: False != True

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

Using this approach, you can add more niceties like printing debugging information on failure, etc.

Comment: +1, on `i think unittest module was blindly copied from junit` and it's not the only one that was copied from java-like :)

Answer (score 12):

**If you are using [pytest](http://pytest.org/) you can go this way:**

```
import pytest

def is_even(number):
    return True # Wuite buggy implementation

@pytest.mark.parametrize("number, expected", [
    (2, True),
    (3, False),
    (4, True),
    (5, False)
])
def test_is_even(number, expected):
    assert is_even(number) == expected
```

You will get something like (shortened):

```
/tmp/test_it.py:13: AssertionError
=========== 2 failed, 2 passed in 0.01 seconds ====================
```

Comment: Maybe mark parametrize didn't exist when the other answers were contributed, but this feels like the correct answer here.

Answer (score 8):

One solution is to make different test case instances for each entry in `data`:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, num, expected):
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self, "evenTest")
        self.num = num
        self.expected = expected
    def evenTest(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.expected, isEven(self.num))
```

For `unittest` to know how to construct the test cases, add a [`load_tests()`](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#load-tests-protocol) function to your module:

```
def load_tests(loader, tests, pattern):
    return unittest.TestSuite(MyTest(num, expected)
                              for num, expected in data)
```

Answer (score 5):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
import unittest


def is_even(number):
    return True # Quite buggy implementation


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.expected_output = [
            (2, True),
            (3, False),
            (4, True),
            (5, False)
        ]

    def test_is_even(self):
        real_res = []

        for arg, _ in self.expected_output:
            real_res.append((arg, is_even(arg)))

        msg_error = '\nFor %s Expected %s Got %s'
        msg = []
        for res1, res2 in zip(real_res, self.expected_output):
            if res1[1] != res2[1]:
                msg.append(msg_error % (res1[0], res1[1], res2[1]))


        self.assertEqual(real_res, self.expected_output, "".join(msg))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_is_even (__main__.TestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in test_example
    self.assertEqual(real_res, self.expected_output, ''.join(msg))
AssertionError:
For 3 Expected True Got False
For 5 Expected True Got False

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: If I had 50 tests, from which 10 fails it will be difficult to find what's going on. For small set of simple test data, it will be very handy and useful. Thanks :)

Comment: @jinowolski: That true, gladly we can customize the error msg as much as we want i edited my answer i don't know if this work for you.

Comment: @Anurag: Which is IMO what it should be, one (simple) function one test, and even if we want to split the tests at least they should all figure out in one Test Case, i can't imagine splitting this in more that one test case specially if this is just a part of a big package, but this is just my humble opinion :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import unittest

data = [
    (2, True),
    (3, False),
    (4, True),
    (5, False)]

# This should be imported from a separate module.
def isEven(number):
    return True # Quite buggy implementation


class TestIsEven(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_is_even(self):
        for num, expected in data:
            self.assertEqual(expected, isEven(num))
```

Comment: This raises on the first error -- read the end of the question again.