# What does the lambda self: do

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1194012/180174) explains how to create test cases dynamically.

The answer's code:

```
class Tests(unittest.TestCase):
    def check(self, i, j):
        self.assertNotEquals(0, i-j)

for i in xrange(1, 4):
    for j in xrange(2, 6):
        def ch(i, j):
            return lambda self: self.check(i, j)
        setattr(Tests, "test_%r_%r" % (i, j), ch(i, j))
```

I've tested and it works, but I can't just figure out *how*?

I have trouble understanding the `lambda self:` magic in play here, mainly:

1. Is the lambda used here to perform the exact opposite of `functools.partial()` (i.e. to create a wrapper function with one *extra* parameter that is not yet known)
2. Is `self` a meaningful keyword or would `lambda spam` would work just as well?
3. What point is that lambda evaluated?
4. How come the `.check()` is perfectly fine outside the `class`es scope?
5. How do you do this *without* lambda? - if I understand correctly, [you should be able to do without `lambda`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3252425/180174) (not to mention that I agree with Guido and Alex that it **is** an eyesore and I *want* to do without :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all: The lambda is returned from a function to prevent that modified values of `i` and `j` will be used later.

Compare to the following:

```
for i in xrange(1, 4):
    for j in xrange(2, 6):
        setattr(Tests, "test_%r_%r" % (i, j), lambda self: self.check(i, j))
```

This will not work as expected, as all the lambdas will share the same namespace and will use the values of `i` and `j` after the end of the loop. If we use a separate function call, we introduce a new closure every time that captures the values of `i` and `j` at the point in time where the function is called.

We could achieve the same by saving the current values of `i` and `j` as default arguments of the lambda. For good measure, let's also use `itertools.product` to avoid the nested loop:

```
from itertools import product
from operator import methodcaller

for i, j in product(range(1, 4), range(2, 6)):
  setattr(Tests, "test_%r_%r" % (i, j),
          lambda self, i=i, j=j: self.check(i, j))
```

> Is the lambda used here to perform the exact opposite of functools.partial() (i.e. to create a wrapper function with one extra parameter that is not yet known)

Not really. It just calls the `check(i, j)` method on whatever it is given as an argument. This is used here to dynamically add methods to the `Tests` class.

> Is self a meaningful keyword or would lambda spam would work just as well?

`spam` would work just as well. They choose `self` here due to convention because the lambda represents a method.

> What point is that lambda evaluated?

As soon as `test_[i]_[j]()` is called on an instance of `Tests`.

> How come the .check() is perfectly fine outside the classes scope?

Because it's inside a lambda will only be called later with an instance of `Tests` as the `self` argument.

Comment: ok "Not really. It just calls the check(i, j) method on whatever it is given as an argument. This is used here to dynamically add methods to the Tests class." was the thing that I did not realize. Now that you mention it, it is self-evident (pun intended)

Comment: The methodcaller modification (which would make the code more readable too, IMO) gives me `TypeError: methodcaller expected 1 arguments, got 0`

Comment: @Kimvais: This is very strange. It seems like the function is not bound correctly when assigned to the class attribute.. This might be due to the fact that it's not a real lambda, but a function defined on the C side of Python. I guess I will open a separate question for that.

Comment: @Kimvais: Meanwhile, you can also use the default argument trick. I edited my answer.

Comment: Another way would be to use define a `make_func(f)` function that just returns a real function: `return lambda *args, **kw: f(*args, **kw)`. Then we can use `methodcaller` like follows: `make_func(methodcaller("check", 1, 2))`.

Comment: Please post the link to the question you will be opening here.

Comment: @Kimvais: Actually I've already answered the question myself using a bit of common sense. What happens is that if you assign a function to a class attribute, it becomes an unbound method. As soon as an instance is created from the class, all the unbound methods are bound to the object instance (that is, they are partially applied to the new `self`). Now if we assign something to a class attribute that is not a function, but only callable, Python doesn't know that we want it to become a method, so it doesn't convert it to an unbound method.

Answer (score 5):

`a_function = lambda x: do_something_with(x)`

is equivalent to

```
def a_function(x):
    return do_something_with(x)
```

In your particular example, the functions created are instance methods. Thus for example you could write:

```
class Tests:
...
   test_1_2 = lambda self: self.check(1, 2)
```

which would be equivalent to:

```
class Tests:
...
   def test_1_2(self):
       return self.check(1, 2)
```

Now, since the identifiers are generated dynamically, hence use of `setattr`.

---

> 1. Is the lambda used here to perform the exact opposite of `functools.partial()` (i.e. to create a wrapper function with one extra
>      parameter that is not yet known)

No, not really. In fact `partial` could be used here as well.

```
test_1_2 = lambda self: self.check(1, 2)
```

would became

```
test_1_2 = partial(Tests.check, i=1, j=2)
```

> 1. Is self a meaningful keyword or would lambda spam would work just as well?

Instance method's first argument always needs to be the instance. The **convention** is to name that parameter `self`, but you can use any other name. I would not advise it, as it will make your code harder to read and understand.

> 1. What point is that lambda evaluated?

`lambda` creates anonymous function, which as any function is evaluated upon call.

> 1. How come the .check() is perfectly fine outside the classes scope?

It isn't. It's `self.check()`, where `self` is an instance of `Tests` class.

Comment: Actually, `operator.methodcaller("check", 1, 2)` is preferrable over `partial` here because it uses duck typing and does not require an instance of `Tests`. This comment also applies to your answer to the other question.

Comment: @NiklasB.: ok, but the question was if `partial` is something opposite of `lambda`, not if that's a best way

Comment: Sure, maybe I should have better added it to your other answer.

Comment: By the way, I just checked it and it seems like the `Tests.method = partial(Tests.check, i=1, j=2)` trick doesn't work (but neither does `Tests.method = operator.methodcaller("check", 1, 2)`). I suspect that the method is not bound correctly because it's not a real function but only a callable, but I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 3):

lambda returns a function. `self` is its argument, and i and j are *enclosed* inside of it

So, ch(i, j) is a **function of i and j** which *returns a function* of **self**.

self does not have any magical meaning here as nothing in Python - every variable and function are explicit except of some built-ins. But as soon as these methods are attached to class, self becomes their 1st argument.

This means

- after the loop The Tests class gets multiple methods called check_i_j
- each of them has values i and j *enclosed* in it
- each of them has their 1st param called `self` which is good cause they are defined inside of class, they are instance methods, and thus their 1st parameter should be called self by convention

Comment: BTW, I thing the code could be much simplified by just writing setattr(Tests, "test_%r_%r" % (i, j), lambda self: self.check(i, j))

Comment: No, that does something completely different.

Comment: @NiklasB. please explain - what's the diference between defining the ch function and instantly calling it and just putting it's value. i and j are enclosed anyway, right?

Comment: All the lambdas will share the same closure, so they will all work with the values of `i` and `j` at the end of the loops. Check my answer for more details. The function call is used in the other answer to force the creating of a new closure for every lambda.

Comment: I know such problem in JS, didn't expect it's applicable to Python. Though now I realize this is the same here

Comment: It's not a problem, you just have to be aware of it.