# What does following code means in python (snippet of locust code)?

Tags: python, locust

I want to understand what `self` means in the `lambda` function.

In the Locust tool I found this code :

```
import random

class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehaviour
    wait_function = lambda self: random.expovariate(1)*1000
```

Can anyone explain what `self` means in the lambda function? Or in short what is happening in this `lambda` function?

Comment: `self` as the first parameter of a method means the instance being used to call the method. Lambda functions work the same as `def` statements.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346239/what-does-the-lambda-self-do

Comment: It's a lambda *expression*, not a lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition is equivalent to

```
class WebsiteUser(HttpLocust):
    task_set = UserBehaviour
    def wait_function(self):
        return random.expovariate(1)*1000
```

`self` is the conventional name for the first argument to an instance method, whether you use a `def` statement or a `lambda` expression to define the method.