# Python library 'unittest': Generate multiple tests programmatically

Tags: python, tdd, unit-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [How do you generate dynamic (parameterized) unit tests in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/how-do-you-generate-dynamic-parameterized-unit-tests-in-python)

I have a function to test, `under_test`, and a set of expected input/output pairs:

```
[
(2, 332),
(234, 99213),
(9, 3),
# ...
]
```

I would like each one of these input/output pairs to be tested in its own `test_*` method. Is that possible?

This is sort of what I want, but forcing every single input/output pair into a single test:

```
class TestPreReqs(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.expected_pairs = [(23, 55), (4, 32)]

    def test_expected(self):
        for exp in self.expected_pairs:
            self.assertEqual(under_test(exp[0]), exp[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

(Also, do I really want to be putting that definition of `self.expected_pairs` in `setUp`?)

**UPDATE:** Trying [**doublep**'s advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798956/python-library-unittest-generate-multiple-tests-programmatically/2799009#2799009):

```
class TestPreReqs(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        expected_pairs = [
                          (2, 3),
                          (42, 11),
                          (3, None),
                          (31, 99),
                         ]

        for k, pair in expected_pairs:
            setattr(TestPreReqs, 'test_expected_%d' % k, create_test(pair))

    def create_test (pair):
        def do_test_expected(self):
            self.assertEqual(get_pre_reqs(pair[0]), pair[1])
        return do_test_expected


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This does not work. 0 tests are run. Did I adapt the example incorrectly?

Comment: `create_test` is supposed to be a free-standing function, not a method of `TestPreReqs`.

Comment: I guess you also cannot install new test methods in `setUp` because by the time `setUp` is called, set of tests is already fixed.  I.e. you can add methods, they just won't be picked up by the testing framework.

Comment: So I think the above implies you should put create_test as a module-level function, and then call it, right before calling unittest.main().

Comment: setUp is called before each test. Since you have no test, setUp would never be called. You could use setUpModule().

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Not tested:

```
class TestPreReqs(unittest.TestCase):
    ...

def create_test (pair):
    def do_test_expected(self):
        self.assertEqual(under_test(pair[0]), pair[1])
    return do_test_expected

for k, pair in enumerate ([(23, 55), (4, 32)]):
    test_method = create_test (pair)
    test_method.__name__ = 'test_expected_%d' % k
    setattr (TestPreReqs, test_method.__name__, test_method)
```

If you use this often, you could prettify this by using utility functions and/or decorators, I guess.  Note that pairs are not an attribute of `TestPreReqs` object in this example (and so `setUp` is gone).  Rather, they are "hardwired" in a sense to the `TestPreReqs` class.

Comment: +1. This is a solution that I have been using successfully on a large project to compare a system generating a timetable with it's expected output. In my experience , although a somewhat hackish solution, it works really really well, as you get a test case for every test and will now exactly where your tests are failing.

Comment: This looks interesting but I wasn't able to get it to work. I updated the OP with my attempt.

Comment: @Rosarch: I guess the problem is in `do_test_expected`'s name.  In edited snippet I change the name dynamically.  This should give an added bonus of a more readable output (a guess, I didn't check this).

Comment: The problem with this technique is that tools such as nose that automatically find and run tests will not find the tests, since they do not exist until the code is executed.

Comment: @Dave Kirby: the code is run at import time so `nose` should find it.

Comment: Since this `.__name__` fix this answer is more correct, than http://stackoverflow.com/a/32939/322020, but is less upvoted and the question is marked as duplicate. It's weird. Also it is older, and I would rather mark as duplicate the new question, not old.

Answer (score 57):

I had to do something similar. I created simple `TestCase` subclasses that took a value in their `__init__`, like this:

```
class KnownGood(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, input, output):
        super(KnownGood, self).__init__()
        self.input = input
        self.output = output
    def runTest(self):
        self.assertEqual(function_to_test(self.input), self.output)
```

I then made a test suite with these values:

```
def suite():
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTests(KnownGood(input, output) for input, output in known_values)
    return suite
```

You can then run it from your main method:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite())
```

The advantages of this are:

- As you add more values, the number of reported tests increases, which makes you feel like you are doing more.
- Each individual test case can fail individually
- It's conceptually simple, since each input/output value is converted into one TestCase

Answer (score 27):

As often with Python, there is a complicated way to provide a simple solution.

In that case, we can use metaprogramming, decorators, and various nifty Python tricks to achieve a nice result. Here is what the final test will look like:

```
import unittest

# Some magic code will be added here later

class DummyTest(unittest.TestCase):
  @for_examples(1, 2)
  @for_examples(3, 4)
  def test_is_smaller_than_four(self, value):
    self.assertTrue(value < 4)

  @for_examples((1,2),(2,4),(3,7))
  def test_double_of_X_is_Y(self, x, y):
    self.assertEqual(2 * x, y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  unittest.main()
```

When executing this script, the result is:

```
..F...F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_double_of_X_is_Y(3,7)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xdecoret/Documents/foo.py", line 22, in method_for_example
    method(self, *example)
  File "/Users/xdecoret/Documents/foo.py", line 41, in test_double_of_X_is_Y
    self.assertEqual(2 * x, y)
AssertionError: 6 != 7

======================================================================
FAIL: test_is_smaller_than_four(4)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xdecoret/Documents/foo.py", line 22, in method_for_example
    method(self, *example)
  File "/Users/xdecoret/Documents/foo.py", line 37, in test_is_smaller_than_four
    self.assertTrue(value < 4)
AssertionError

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

which achieves our goal:

- it is unobtrusive: we derive from TestCase as usual
- we write parametrized tests only once
- each example value is considered an individual test
- the decorator can be stacked, so it is easy to use sets of examples (e.g., using a function to build the list of values from example files or directories)
- The icing on the cake is it works for arbitrary arity of the signature

So how does it work? Basically, the decorator stores the examples in an attribute of the function. We use a metaclass to replace every decorated function with a list of functions. And we replace the unittest.TestCase with our new magic code (to be pasted in the "magic" comment above) is:

```
__examples__ = "__examples__"

def for_examples(*examples):
    def decorator(f, examples=examples):
      setattr(f, __examples__, getattr(f, __examples__,()) + examples)
      return f
    return decorator

class TestCaseWithExamplesMetaclass(type):
  def __new__(meta, name, bases, dict):
    def tuplify(x):
      if not isinstance(x, tuple):
        return (x,)
      return x
    for methodname, method in dict.items():
      if hasattr(method, __examples__):
        dict.pop(methodname)
        examples = getattr(method, __examples__)
        delattr(method, __examples__)
        for example in (tuplify(x) for x in examples):
          def method_for_example(self, method = method, example = example):
            method(self, *example)
          methodname_for_example = methodname + "(" + ", ".join(str(v) for v in example) + ")"
          dict[methodname_for_example] = method_for_example
    return type.__new__(meta, name, bases, dict)

class TestCaseWithExamples(unittest.TestCase):
  __metaclass__ = TestCaseWithExamplesMetaclass
  pass

unittest.TestCase = TestCaseWithExamples
```

If someone wants to package this nicely, or propose a patch for *unittest*, feel free! A quote of my name will be appreciated.

The code can be made much simpler and fully encapsulated in the decorator if you are ready to use frame introspection (import the *sys* module)

```
def for_examples(*parameters):

  def tuplify(x):
    if not isinstance(x, tuple):
      return (x,)
    return x

  def decorator(method, parameters=parameters):
    for parameter in (tuplify(x) for x in parameters):

      def method_for_parameter(self, method=method, parameter=parameter):
        method(self, *parameter)
      args_for_parameter = ",".join(repr(v) for v in parameter)
      name_for_parameter = method.__name__ + "(" + args_for_parameter + ")"
      frame = sys._getframe(1)  # pylint: disable-msg=W0212
      frame.f_locals[name_for_parameter] = method_for_parameter
    return None
  return decorator
```

Comment: For some reason, nosetests.selector doesn't seem to find tests decorated in this way.

Comment: FIXED:  adding ``method_for_parameter.__name__ = name_for_parameter``  to the decorator style one ensures that nosetest will find the tests

Comment: Nifty stuff. This pattern is the only thing that I miss in the standard library, compared to nose. :)

Comment: Also adding doc to `frame.f_locals[name_for_parameter].__doc__ = method.__doc__` (or to `method_for_parameter`) allows docstring printing for failed test.

Answer (score 13):

#### [nose](https://pypi.org/project/nose/) (suggested by [@Paul Hankin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798956/python-unittest-generate-multiple-tests-programmatically/2798970#2798970))

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# file: test_pairs_nose.py
from nose.tools import eq_ as eq

from mymodule import f

def test_pairs():
    for input, output in [ (2, 332), (234, 99213), (9, 3), ]:
        yield _test_f, input, output

def _test_f(input, output):
    try:
        eq(f(input), output)
    except AssertionError:
        if input == 9: # expected failure
            from nose.exc import SkipTest
            raise SkipTest("expected failure")
        else:
            raise

if __name__=="__main__":
   import nose; nose.main()
```

Example:

```
$ nosetests test_pairs_nose -v
test_pairs_nose.test_pairs(2, 332) ... ok
test_pairs_nose.test_pairs(234, 99213) ... ok
test_pairs_nose.test_pairs(9, 3) ... SKIP: expected failure

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

OK (SKIP=1)
```

#### [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) (an approach similar to [@doublep's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798956/python-unittest-generate-multiple-tests-programmatically/2799009#2799009))

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import unittest2 as unittest
from mymodule import f

def add_tests(generator):
    def class_decorator(cls):
        """Add tests to `cls` generated by `generator()`."""
        for f, input, output in generator():
            test = lambda self, i=input, o=output, f=f: f(self, i, o)
            test.__name__ = "test_%s(%r, %r)" % (f.__name__, input, output)
            setattr(cls, test.__name__, test)
        return cls
    return class_decorator

def _test_pairs():
    def t(self, input, output):
        self.assertEqual(f(input), output)

    for input, output in [ (2, 332), (234, 99213), (9, 3), ]:
        tt = t if input != 9 else unittest.expectedFailure(t)
        yield tt, input, output

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    pass
TestCase = add_tests(_test_pairs)(TestCase)

if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Example:

```
$ python test_pairs_unit2.py -v
test_t(2, 332) (__main__.TestCase) ... ok
test_t(234, 99213) (__main__.TestCase) ... ok
test_t(9, 3) (__main__.TestCase) ... expected failure

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.000s

OK (expected failures=1)
```

If you don't want to install `unittest2` then add:

```
try:
    import unittest2 as unittest
except ImportError:
    import unittest
    if not hasattr(unittest, 'expectedFailure'):
       import functools
       def _expectedFailure(func):
           @functools.wraps(func)
           def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
               try:
                   func(*args, **kwargs)
               except AssertionError:
                   pass
               else:
                   raise AssertionError("UnexpectedSuccess")
           return wrapper
       unittest.expectedFailure = _expectedFailure
```

Answer (score 7):

Some of the tools available for doing parametrized tests in Python are:

- [Nose test generators](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators) (only for function tests, not TestCase classes)
- [nose-parametrized](https://github.com/wolever/nose-parameterized) by David Wolever (also for TestCase classes)
- [Unittest template](http://feldboris.alwaysdata.net/blog/unittest-template.html) by Boris Feld
- [Parametrized tests in py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/funcargs.html#parametrized-test-functions)
- [parametrized-testcase](http://code.google.com/p/parameterized-testcase/) by Austin Bingham

See also [question 1676269](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676269/writing-a-re-usable-parametrized-unittest-testcase-method/12740930) for more answers to this question.

Answer (score 3):

I think [Rory's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798956/python-unittest-generate-multiple-tests-programmatically/3772008#3772008) is the cleanest and shortest. However, this variation of [doublep's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798956/python-unittest-generate-multiple-tests-programmatically/2799009#2799009) "create synthetic functions in a TestCase"  also works:

```
from functools import partial

class TestAllReports(unittest.TestCase):
    pass

def test_spamreport(name):
    assert classify(getSample(name))=='spamreport', name

for rep in REPORTS:
    testname = 'test_' + rep
    testfunc = partial(test_spamreport, rep)
    testfunc.__doc__ = testname
    setattr(TestAllReports, testname, testfunc)

if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main(argv=sys.argv + ['--verbose'])
```