# Python unittest - invoke unittest.main() with a custom TestSuite

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'm making unittests with python. I am not using any automatical test discovery. I am assembling `TestCases` into a `TestSuite` manually.

I can run these tests with `unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)`, I would like to run them with `unittest.main()` so that I can use command line options (like `-v`/`--failfast`). The documentation says that `unittest.main()` can take a TestRunner option.

How to convert my `TestSuite` into a `TestRunner`?

Comment: TestSuite and TestRunner have **nothing** to do with each other.  A suite is a collection of tests.  A runner executes a collection of tests.  You don't turn one into the other.  You provide the suite to the runner (via `unittest.main()`, usually.)

Comment: How do I provide a testsuite to unittest.main()? Or how do I make a TestRunner that will run a given TestSuite (that I can pass to unittest.main())

Comment: Are you just trying to pass `failfast` to your TestRunner?  If you read the source, an undocumented feature of testrunner is that it accepts the `failfast` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Near duplicate of [How to run a testsuite with unittest.main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13343142/how-to-run-a-testsuite-with-unittest-main#13343607) (answer copy-and-pasted):

You can't pass a `TestSuite` to main, check out the constructor of `unittest.main.TestProgram` (which is was `unittest.main` actually is) and how this class works. The first argument if anything is the module name, not a testsuite.

`main()` actually takes its arguments from `sys.argv`, as it is actually intended to be used from the command line and not from within a program. It's just common to do so for convenience.

Answer (score -4):

Do nothing except be sure you have this in your unit test module.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(failfast=True)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.main

From the documentation...

```
unittest.main( failfast=True, testRunner=unittest.TextTestRunner )
```

Comment: I am not using unittest.main()'s test autodiscovery, I am hand crafting a TestSuite. If I use unittest.main as you suggest it won't run my tests. I've tried.

Comment: Why hand-cract?  Why won't main autodiscover your tests?  What are your test superclasses?  What are your test names?  It works perfectly for me.  What are you doing wrong?

Comment: I am not using autodiscover because I am making TestCases based on known valid inputs for a function. I am using this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798956/python-unittest-generate-multiple-tests-programmatically/3772008#3772008

Comment: @Rory: That approach seems silly.  Why not put the loop in `runTest` where it's supposed to be?  Why create a complex suite when you could move the complexity into one test case that simply iterates through the values?

Comment: @S.Lott see the benefits I listed in that answer.

Comment: @Rory: I did see those "benefits".  I don't agree with them.  They aren't "beneficial".  This question -- indeed -- is evidence that it's actually harmful, not helpful.