# How to run a testsuite with unittest.main

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python unittest - invoke unittest.main() with a custom TestSuite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772074/python-unittest-invoke-unittest-main-with-a-custom-testsuite)

I have a testsuite created with e.g.

```
suite = unittest.TestSuite()
suite.addTest(module1.MyTest("test_simple"))
suite.addTest(module2.MyTest("test_simple"))
```

and need to start these tests with `unitest.main()`. When trying just `unitest.main(suite)` no tests are run at all. How can I do this with `unittest.main()` without calling `test.TextTestRunner` or similar?

Comment: You need a runner to run tests. Why don't you want to use one?

Comment: I do not need a runner, when I create a single TestCase in a code and call unittest.main().

Comment: @Piotr No its not a duplicate. The question in the given link is similar, but has never been answered (correctly). Or maybe I do not understand the answer.

Comment: The fact it hasn't been answered does not change the fact the two ask about the same.

Comment: Agreed. But the fact that the question is about the same does not change the fact that it is still not answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass a `TestSuite` to main, check out the constructor of [`unittest.main.TestProgram`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6a6ad09faad2/Lib/unittest/main.py#l81) (which is was `unittest.main` actually is) and how this class works. The first argument if anything is the module name, not a testsuite.

`main()` actually takes its arguments from `sys.argv`, as it is actually intended to be used from the command line and not from within a program. It's just common to do so for convenience.

Comment: Does this mean, that what I want is impossible (or, at least, would be very circumstantial to achieve)?

Comment: it's not what unittest.main is made for, you should better use a testrunner.

Comment: Ok, then I have to look for another way of handling this. Thanks

Comment: You might consider answering the original one as well. Thanks.

Comment: Done: Original question answered with same answer from mata