# Pytest is not called for every row when running in loop

Tags: pytest, pytest-cov

I am trying to execute the below pytest function in loop after reading a row from file

```
import pandas as pd  
import pytest

def test_assert_kwh(record_xml_property):
    test_df=pd.read_csv('test_function.txt',sep="|",header=0)
    print(test_df.head(10))
    for index,row in test_df.iterrows():
         test_function=row['test_function']
         test_op=row['test_op']
         test_class=row['test_class']
         print ( "Test Function ",test_function)
         assert eval(test_function)== test_op
```

File1.txt content :

```
test_function|test_op|test_class
fun_1(0,0)|0|data_transformation
fun_1(0,0)|1|data_transformation
```

Pytest is only getting executed once and not twice , though there are two rows in the file

O/p is coming as one passed , though there are two rows which are to be tested

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run multiple Python test cases in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071601/how-do-i-run-multiple-python-test-cases-in-a-loop)

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: What makes you think the second row is not tested? What is the actual test output (what `pytest` is printing), and what did you expect to see?