# Unable to run unittest test suite (using TestCase subclasses) in PyCharm, whereas it runs in Python console

Tags: python, pycharm, python-unittest

I am following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772008/2396316) to generate multiple test cases programmatically using the unittest approach.

Here's the code:

```
import unittest
import my_code

# Test cases (List of input output pairs not explicitly mentioned here)
known_values = [
    {'input': {}, 'output': {}}, 
    {'input': {}, 'output': {}}
]

# Subclass TestCase
class KnownGood(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, input_params, output):
        super(KnownGood, self).__init__()
        self.input_params = input_params
        self.output = output
    
    def runTest(self):
        self.assertEqual(
            my_code.my_func(self.input_params['a'], self.input_params['b']),
            self.output
        )

# Test suite
def suite():
    global known_values
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTests(KnownGood(input_params=k['input'], output=k['output']) for k in known_values)
    return suite

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite())
```

If I open a Python console in PyCharm and run the above code chunk (running `unittest.TextTestRunner()` without the if condition), the tests run successfully.

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s
OK
<unittest.runner.TextTestResult run=2 errors=0 failures=0>
```

If I run the test by clicking on the green run button for the `if __name__` block in PyCharm, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'output'

Process finished with exit code 1

Empty suite

Empty suite
```

Python version: 3.7

Project structure: (`-` denotes folder and `.` denotes file)

```
-project_folder
    -tests
      .test_my_code.py
    .my_code.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that PyCharm by default is running `unittest` or `pytest` (whatever you have configured as test runner) on the module if it identifies it as containing tests, ignoring the part in `if __name__ == '__main__'`.
That basically means that it executes `unittest.main()` instead of your customized version of running the tests.

The only solution I know to get the correct run configuration is to manually add it:

- select `Edit configurations...` in the configuration list
- add a new config using `+`
- select `Python` as type
- fill in the `Script path` by your test path (or use the browse button)

Maybe someone knows a more convenient way to force PyCharm to use "Run" instead of "Run Test"...

Comment: I see. That makes a lot of sense after your explanation (although the "feature" did cause some of my hair to spontaneously part ways with my scalp). :)

Comment: Yeah, I've run into this too, and would have liked an easier solution...