# Python parameterized unittest by subclassing TestCase

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, inheritance, python-unittest

How can I create multiple TestCases and run them programmatically?  I'm trying to test multiple implementations of a collection on a common TestCase.

I'd prefer to stick to with plain unittest and avoid dependencies.

Here's some resources that I looked at that didn't quite meet what I wanted:

- [Writing a re-usable parametrized unittest.TestCase method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676269/) - The accepted answer proposes four different external libraries.
- http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/02/python-unit-testing-parametrized-test-cases -
  This approach uses a static method `paramerize`. I don't understand why you can't pass in a parameter directly into the
  `TestSubClass.__init__`.
- [How to generate dynamic (parametrized) unit tests in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/) - A little bit too black magic.

Here's a minimal (non)working example.

```
import unittest

MyCollection = set
AnotherCollection = set
# ... many more collections


def maximise(collection, array):
    return 2


class TestSubClass(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, collection_class):
        unittest.TestCase.__init__(self)
        self.collection_class = collection_class
        self.maximise_fn = lambda array: maximise(collection_class, array)


    def test_single(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.maximise_fn([1]), 1)


    def test_overflow(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.maximise_fn([3]), 1)

    # ... many more tests


def run_suite():
    suite = unittest.defaultTestLoader
    for collection in [MyCollection, AnotherCollection]:
        suite.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestSubClass(collection))
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)


def main():
    run_suite()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The above approach errors with in `loadTestsFromTestCase`:

`TypeError: issubclass() arg 1 must be a class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`pytest` with to parametrize fixture](https://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixture-parametrize):

```
import pytest

MyCollection = set
AnotherCollection = set


def maximise(collection, array):
    return 1

@pytest.fixture(scope='module', params=[MyCollection, AnotherCollection])
def maximise_fn(request):
    return lambda array: maximise(request.param, array)

def test_single(maximise_fn):
    assert maximise_fn([1]) == 1

def test_overflow(maximise_fn):
    assert maximise_fn([3]) == 1
```

If that's not an option, you can make a mixin to contain test function, and subclasses to provide `maximise_fn`s:

```
import unittest

MyCollection = set
AnotherCollection = set


def maximise(collection, array):
    return 1


class TestCollectionMixin:
    def test_single(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.maximise_fn([1]), 1)

    def test_overflow(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.maximise_fn([3]), 1)


class TestMyCollection(TestCollectionMixin, unittest.TestCase):
    maximise_fn = lambda self, array: maximise(MyCollection, array)


class TestAnotherCollection(TestCollectionMixin, unittest.TestCase):
    maximise_fn = lambda self, array: maximise(AnotherCollection, array)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Nice, the mixin idea is about perfect.  It's a little repetitive but very clear.

Comment: The CPython test suite uses the mixin approach to test, for instance, C and Python implementations or, for instance, tests common to more than one class, such as unicode and bytes or tuples and lists (and even range) or sets  and frozensets.