# Proper way to organize testcases that involve a data file for each testcase?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

I'm writing a module that involves parsing html for data and creating an object from it. Basically, I want to create a set of testcases where each case is an html file paired with a golden/expected pickled object file.

As I make changes to the parser, I would like to run this test suite to ensure that each html page is parsed to equal the 'golden' file (essentially a regression suite)

I can see how to code this as a single test case, where I would load all file pairs from some directory and then iterate through them. But I believe this would end up being reported as a single test case, pass or fail. But I want a report that says, for example, 45/47 pages parsed successfully.

How do I arrange this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done similar things with the `unittest` framework by writing a function which creates and returns a test class. This function can then take in whatever parameters you want and customise the test class accordingly. You can also customise the `__doc__` attribute of the test function(s) to get customised messages when running the tests.

I quickly knocked up the following example code to illustrate this. Instead of doing any actual testing, it uses the `random` module to fail some tests for demonstration purposes. When created, the classes are inserted into the global namespace so that a call to `unittest.main()` will pick them up. Depending on how you run your tests, you may wish to do something different with the generated classes.

```
import os
import unittest

# Generate a test class for an individual file.
def make_test(filename):
    class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_file(self):
            # Do the actual testing here.
            # parsed = do_my_parsing(filename)
            # golden = load_golden(filename)
            # self.assertEquals(parsed, golden, 'Parsing failed.')

            # Randomly fail some tests.
            import random
            if not random.randint(0, 10):
                self.assertEquals(0, 1, 'Parsing failed.')

        # Set the docstring so we get nice test messages.
        test_file.__doc__ = 'Test parsing of %s' % filename

    return TestClass

# Create a single file test.
Test1 = make_test('file1.html')

# Create several tests from a list.
for i in range(2, 5):
    globals()['Test%d' % i] = make_test('file%d.html' % i)

# Create them from a directory listing.
for dirname, subdirs, filenames in os.walk('tests'):
    for f in filenames:
        globals()['Test%s' % f] = make_test('%s/%s' % (dirname, f))

# If this file is being run, run all the tests.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

A sample run:

```
$ python tests.py -v
Test parsing of file1.html ... ok
Test parsing of file2.html ... ok
Test parsing of file3.html ... ok
Test parsing of file4.html ... ok
Test parsing of tests/file5.html ... ok
Test parsing of tests/file6.html ... FAIL
Test parsing of tests/file7.html ... ok
Test parsing of tests/file8.html ... ok

======================================================================
FAIL: Test parsing of tests/file6.html
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generic.py", line 16, in test_file
    self.assertEquals(0, 1, 'Parsing failed.')
AssertionError: Parsing failed.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 8 tests in 0.004s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The nose testing framework supports this. http://www.somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/

Also see here: [How to generate dynamic (parametrized) unit tests in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/how-to-generate-dynamic-unit-tests-in-python)

Here's what I would do (untested):

```
files = os.listdir("/path/to/dir")

class SomeTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def _compare_files(self, file_name): 
        with open('/path/to/dir/%s-golden' % file_name, 'r') as golden:  
            with open('/path/to/dir/%s-trial' % file_name, 'r') as trial:    
                assert golden.read() == trial.read()     


def test_generator(file_name):
    def test(self):
        self._compare_files(file_name):
    return test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for file_name in files:
        test_name = 'test_%s' % file_name
        test = test_generator(file_name)
        setattr(SomeTests, test_name, test)
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Well obviously I could do that... but any decent solution shouldn't hardcode the number/names of files/testcases. It should load whatever is in a directory, or filelist, etc.