# How to make unit test in pyCharm

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7, pycharm

I want to make some unit tests, so I set up a list with values that all should be asserted true, just like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/how-to-generate-dynamic-unit-tests-in-python). But I want it to run in [`PyCharm`](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) (With pressing `Alt`+`Shift`+`F10`)

If I just use the code from the answers, I just get `No tests were found`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to double check the settings for the tests run configuration:

[image: settings]

By default PyCharm will inspect files that start with `test` and that are subclasses of `unittest.TestCase`, however you can control the **Pattern** and the subclasses option.

Change **Pattern** according to your test file names, it accepts Python regular expression.

Comment: That filename started with "test*" pattern were really helped me. And it is case sensitive...

Answer (score 1):

Note that PyCharm will inspect only classes that inherit from unittest.TestCase so you should write the tests inside a class inherited from unittest.TestCase

Comment: That's not true. PyCharm supports `py.test` which does not require any test classes to extend `unittest.TestCase` (`py.test` promises no APIs)

Answer (score 0):

#### PyCharm 2019.1+ and pytest

First, create a file named pytest.ini in order to set up custom configurations. For example, by default `pytest` will consider any file matching with `test_*.py` and `*_test.py` globs as a test module, so I encourage to have this file in order to define your custom file name patterns.

**pytest.ini**

```
[pytest]
python_files = test_*.py tests.py *_test.py
```

Now, open up the **Run/Configuration** window:

[image]

Add a new configuration, select Python tests and pytest:

[image]

In the following window you choose a name for your configuration, and you can also choose the target, but if you want pytest to use the `pytest.ini` file do not select Script path, APPLY, and OK.

[image]

Finally, run the test by clicking on the Play button.

[image]