# Running Python package unit tests in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, python-unittest

I just 'ported' a Python package I'm writing to PyCharm and having a bit of trouble running unit tests for the whole package from the IDE.

In `__init__.py` for the package I have `load_tests` function that goes over all modules in the package and loads relevant tests. It runs splendidly with:

```
$python -m unittest my_package
```

However, when I try running it from PyCharm (by selecting the top directory in the Projects window and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>) I get `No tests were found` in the Run window, and

```
...\python.exe ...\pycharm\utrunner.py .../my_package/ true
Testing started at ...
Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.
```

in the console window.

I took a quick look at PyCharm's `utrunner.py` and it seems that it is looking for modules with a certain pattern (that start with *test*). I would like to preserve the present vanilla approach. How can I configure PyCharm to use `load_tests` from `__init__.py` while modifying the code as little as possible?

By the way, test suites for individual modules run just fine from PyCharm.

Using PyCharm 3.1 Community Edition, Python 2.7.

Answer (score 5):

This answer has been written considering PyCharm 3.4.

Had the same problem, found solution for the problem in this answer, hope I understood your question right:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12242021/2427749

I configured my Python Test runner configuration like this:

- Checked 'All in Folder'
- Pattern is the Regular Expression '.*_Test.py' (without quotes)
- Checked 'Inspect only subclass for unittest.TestCase'.

Now it finds my unitests in my subfolders named like `classToBeTested_Test.py`

by the way, I'm facing another problem now: the unit test cannot import the module to be tested. Cause of different root folder I think.

Comment: You can add a different root folder in `Settings > Project Structure > Add Content Root`.

Comment: Just an FYI, for others... it took me a little while, but "pattern" uses a **regex**, not a regular shell glob like `*Test.py`.  If use something like that the test runner will crash.  I didn't realize it wanted a regex until I looked at the stack trace!

Comment: Just to complete for those folks which might not know all about regex, a single start ( * ) will not search recursively, use two stars for that.

e.g.: `**_test.py`

Comment: @Memophysic at least for me, that's illegal syntax in regex (multiple repeat with no previous pattern). That looks like glob.

Comment: @VillasV Indeed, but it works in PyCharm. I'm unaware of how the JetBrain folks implemented it though. PyCharm is coded in Java after all. Anyways ** is quite common now, even glob works with it since 3.5.

Answer (score 2):

With PyCharm 2016.2 use:

- *Test*: Script
- *Script*: `/path/to/tests/__init__.py`
- Check *Inspect only subclasses of unittest.TestCase*. This causes `utrunner` to use `unittest.TestLoader.loadTestsFromModule()` and that method call `load_tests()` if present in the module.

I.e. the command is

```
python C:\python\pycharm\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py /path/to/tests/__init__.py true
```

I had to remove the tests directory from the `sys.path` in the `__init__.py` as well (see [PY-15889](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-15889)):

```
basedir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
try:
    sys.path.remove(basedir)
except ValueError:
    pass
```