# Pycharm - no django tests found but run in console

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pycharm

I followed this tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial05/

The tests can be run by the command (`polls` is the application name)

```
python manage.py test polls
```

However under PyCharm IDEA, when I click on the green arrow (line 21-22).

The message is "No tests were found"

[image]

The stack trace is gibberish to me

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/Applications/PyCharm
> CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pycharm/_jb_unittest_runner.py",
> line 35, in 
> sys.exit(main(argv=args, module=None, testRunner=unittestpy.TeamcityTestRunner, buffer=not
> JB_DISABLE_BUFFERING))   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py",
> line 100, in **init**
> self.parseArgs(argv)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py",
> line 147, in parseArgs
> self.createTests()   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/main.py",
> line 159, in createTests
> self.module)   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py",
> line 220, in loadTestsFromNames
> suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py",
> line 220, in 
> suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]   File
> "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.7/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/unittest/loader.py",
> line 154, in loadTestsFromName
> module = **import**(module_name)   File "/Users/raychenon/Projects/python/django/mysite/polls/test_views.py",
> line 8, in 
> from .models import Question   File "/Users/raychenon/Projects/python/django/mysite/polls/models.py", line
> 8, in 
> class Question(models.Model):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 107, in **new**
> app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line
> 252, in get_containing_app_config
> self.check_apps_ready()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line
> 134, in check_apps_ready
> settings.INSTALLED_APPS   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line
> 76, in **getattr**
> self._setup(name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line
> 61, in _setup
> % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)) django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting
> INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either
> define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call
> settings.configure() before accessing settings.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1
>
> Empty suite

### PyCharm IDE setup

My python interpreter is set correctly
[image]

### Research

I already looked at [Pycharm - no tests were found?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35964848/pycharm-no-tests-were-found) . Unrelated error, my test functions names start by `test_*`

Comment: Have you setup your python interpreter properly?

Comment: Of course, James, my IDE can run Python but it doesn't find the Django dependencies

Comment: That means your interpreter has not been setup properly.

Comment: hi @RaymondChenon, is it possible you accepted the wrong answer? that one just tells you to set up the interpreter even when you say your interpreter is fine. I am asking because I saw someone upvoted my answer and at the same time you accepted that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment saying your django dependencies cannot be found, I suspect you didn't setup the python interpreter properly for your project.

Eg. if you use virtualenv, you need to setup your python interpreter to point to the python bin inside your virtualenv, so Pycharm can find your packages.

Eg. photo below shows the python interpreter for my "pmas" virtualenv.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason we use `manage.py` when working with Django is that it *manages* environment for us.

But working with pycharm, unless you specify things manually, a python file that has test footprints in it (importing unittest and having method names startng with "test_") are just modules we can test without any external dependencies.

in cases you use a framework such as Django, then you need to play by their rules. you will either use their tools or set whatever is needed manually.

I don't know if pycharm had this support at the time but this [pycharm/django-support](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/django-support7.html#versions) may help.

if that does not cover your needs, then you will need to work on a few things mentioned in [Django Settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings) (check for other versions if you use an older one, or newer if you are from the future). your error message already mentions about this.

```
Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured.
You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

- you can either open project settings in pycharm and add this key-value in environment variables for it:
  `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings`
- or use this in your code wherever it is needed. (check the settings page for details)

```
    from django.conf import settings
    settings.configure(DEBUG=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysites.settings

here, mysites is name of Django project where settings.py is available
```

paste the above line in bash shell before running standalone python script