# continue test after assertion fail using xmlrunner and unittest in python

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing, jenkins

I am writing a simple test using XMLrunner and unittest in python. When using assert the test fails and does not continue. I want the test to continue to the end and then fail. Is it possible? I will attach a very simple code demostrating what I need to do.

```
import xmlrunner
import unittest

class TestExp(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.list = range(1,10)

    def test_example(self):
        for i in self.list:
            self.assertTrue(i == 3, str(i) + "message")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(
        testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='test-reports'),
        failfast=False, buffer=False, catchbreak=False)
```

as an output an XML is generated, however containing only the first failed assertion, I need to run the rest of the assertions and also generate test-reports from them, when using try/except i cannot see the testcase fail in XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<testsuite errors="1" failures="0" name="TestExp-20150429152621" tests="1" time="0.000">
    <testcase classname="TestExp" name="test_example" time="0.000">
        <error message="1message" type="AssertionError">
<![CDATA[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xmlrunsample.py", line 14, in test_example
    self.assertTrue(i == 3, str(i) + "message")
AssertionError: 1message
]]>     </error>
    </testcase>
    <system-out>
<![CDATA[]]>    </system-out>
    <system-err>
<![CDATA[]]>    </system-err>
</testsuite>
```

This is what i get as test-report output, containing only 1 assertion fail, how can i make the script continue to assert the rest of test cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are structuring your tests the wrong way. The test runner sees this as a single test. When it catches an assertion, the test failes.

If you want to stay close to your code, you have to catch the assertions yourself, and re-throw one in the end. This is obviously smelly code, as it makes the origin of the fail opaque.

Ideally you'd have to re-engineer your tests. **If you have assertions which are independent of each other (i.e. you are interested in the next one, even if the previous failed), you have independent test cases**. The Testrunner is responsible for iteration through your tests, and it will catch each assertion and output it.

Look at [the fine documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) on how to do it.

If you are looking for parametrized test cases, [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32939/450517) is an idea, on which you can start.

Comment: not sure i understand, its the first time i am doing this, could u please give me more details or a hint on how to do it? thx

Comment: Lets say i want to test numbers 1 through 1000 and test every one if it is even. Before i just tested it with a condition and appended the bug to an array if the condition returned false. But now I need to do the same thing, but with all the odd numbers listed as errors in XML test report file.

Comment: I need the proper JUnit XML output, because this test should run automatically in JIRA(of course not exactly this test, but the problem i have is the same)

Comment: you need parametrized tests (look at the link), e.g. a generator for a number of alike tests