# How do I convert a unittest subtest to pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, python-unittest

Does `pytest` (2.8.3) have an equivalent of `self.subTest()` (as found in Python 3's `unittest`)?

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm trying to convert:

```
class MyUnittestTest(TestCase):
    def test_permutations(self):
        on_off = True, False
        for prefix, params, suffix in product(on_off, on_off, on_off):

            expected_prefix = 'something' if prefix else ''
            expected_params = ('something',) if params else ()
            expected_suffix = b'something' if suffix else b''

            with self.subTest(prefix=prefix, params=params, suffix=suffix):
                result = do_magic(prefix=prefix, params=params, suffix=suffix)

                self.assertEqual(result.prefix, expected_prefix)
                self.assertEqual(result.params, expected_params)
                self.assertEqual(result.suffix, expected_suffix)
```

At the moment, all I have is defining one test per permutation. There must be a better way than this:

```
class MyPytestTest:
    def test_on_on_on(self):
        expected_prefix = ...

        result = do_magic(...)

        assert ...

    def test_on_on_off(self):
        ...
```

Comment: Use `pytest.mark.parametrize` - see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/32899/3001761

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pytest does not have this functionality natively, but it can be added with the [`pytest-subtests`](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-subtests/) plugin.

To use it, inject the `subtests` fixture into the test:

```py
def test_permutations(subtests):
    on_off = True, False
    for prefix, params, suffix in product(on_off, on_off, on_off):
        with subtests.test(prefix=prefix, params=params, suffix=suffix):
            result = do_magic(prefix=prefix, params=params, suffix=suffix)
            assert ...
```

In some cases [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/parametrize.html) may be a better alternative, though it does not work in the same way.