# Are eval Versions of unittest's assert* A Good Idea?

Tags: python, exception, eval, python-unittest

It's generally accepted that using [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) is bad practice. The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice) states that there is almost always a better alternative. However, the [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module in the standard library uses it, and I stumbled onto a case where I can't find a better alternative.

The [`unittest` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#) has assertion functions of the form

```
self.assert*(..., msg=None)
```

allowing to assert something, optionally printing `msg` if it failed. This allows running code like

```
for i in range(1, 20):
    self.assertEqual(foo(i), i, str(i) + ' failed')
```

Now consider the case where `foo` can raise an exception, e.g.,

```
def foo(i):
    if i % 5 == 0:
        raise ValueError()
    return i
```

then

1. On the one hand, `msg` won't be printed, as `assertEqual` was technically never called for the offending iteration.
2. On the other hand, fundamentally, `foo(i) == i` failed to be true (admittedly because `foo(i)` never finished executing), and so this is a case where it would be useful to print `msg`.

I would like a version that prints out `msg` even if the failure cause was an exception - this will allow to understand exactly which invocation failed. Using `eval`, I could do this by writing a version taking strings, such as the following (which is a somewhat simplified version just to illustrate the point):

```
def assertEqual(lhs, rhs, msg=None):
    try:
        lhs_val = eval(lhs)
        rhs_val = eval(rhs)
        if lhs_val != rhs_val:
            raise ValueError()
    except:
        if msg is not None:
            print msg
        raise
```

and then using

```
for i in range(1, 20):
    self.assertEqual('foo(i)', 'i', str(i) + ' failed')
```

Of course technically it's possible to do it completely differently, by placing each call to `assert*` within a `try/except/finally`, but I could only think of extremely verbose alternatives (that also required duplicating `msg`.)

Is the use of `eval` legitimate here, then, or is there a better alternative?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: @snakecharmerb As is stated in the question, running the snippet following "This allows running code like", and having `msg` be printed out at the iteration that failed.

Comment: Sure, but how is that better than getting the existing behaviour? I don't see the advantage of this over just reading the stacktrace and exception message that you get for free.

Comment: @snakecharmerb IINM, a stacktrace will not show you at what iteration an exception was thrown, no?

Comment: that's true.  Do you need something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/34094/5320906?

Comment: Perhaps you need a more informative exception then: `raise ValueError('Invalid value {0!r}'.format(i))`

Comment: @snakecharmerb Many thanks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If an exception is raised *unexpectedly*, that would point to a bug in your code. Exactly the case you want to discover with your unit tests. It's not simply *not equal*, it's a bug you discovered that you need to fix.

If you *expect* an exception to be raised, assert that with:

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
    foo(i)
```

If you expect *no* exception to be raised, use:

```
try:
    foo(i)
except ValueError:
    self.fail("foo() raised ValueEror unexpectedly!")
```

If anything, I'd suggest you write your own wrapper like:

```
self.assertEqualsAndCatch(foo, i, msg=...)
```

I.e.: pass a callback and its arguments, instead of a string to `eval`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe that what you suggest here is exactly what I wrote in the penultimate paragraph in my question as being a viable, yet verbose, alternative. I'd prefer avoiding having each call enclosed by a `try/except/finally` construct - it lowers the code's SNR.

Comment: I don't see it as verbose. Granted, it takes *extra lines*. But it's readable, it provides the relevant information when a failure happens that should not. Because, as stated by deceze's answer, if your unittest actually raises something, that means you caught a bug you should have tested for.

Comment: @Ami I don't think you should be *asserting* anything when you *expect* an exception to be raised! Looping over 20 integers knowing that half of them *won't* work, yet writing an assert that *expects* them to work is weird. If you take out the positive assertion, there's no duplicate message and it's not terribly verbose either.

Comment: @deceze Thanks again for your comment. I am not *expecting* anything to be raised - If I were, I'd use `assertRaises`.

Comment: @Ami That's my point then: if you expect that *no* exception be raised and to just receive a comparable result, then your unit test should do a plain `assertEquals`; if and when an exception actually *is* raised: congratulations, you found a bug that must be fixed! You should absolutely not suppress that into a simple "oops, not equal".

Comment: I agree. Especially as a developer, you do not want to suppress a Stacktrace. You *want* to know what happened. Because it should not have happened.

Comment: @idjaw This answer is good and has its points. However, I'd have to disagree on verbosity, though - imagine if this were repeated in may `unittest` methods - this construct would repeat itself. To me, that's an indication that there's boilerplate code and verbosity going on. Having said that, again, it's not that I think this answer is not good. I am hoping for an alternative approach, though (using `eval` or preferably not).

Comment: @idjaw I do not think that the stacktrace must be suppressed, though - this is a minimal version of the code, but there are facilities for printing the stacktrace or sending the exception higher.

Comment: @Ami What I'm trying to tell you is that I think your premise is entirely flawed. Why would you want to handle an ***exception***, an *exceptional case* which should not happen, the same as a faulty calculation? Perhaps your API is badly designed and is raising exceptions as a "normal" case...?

Comment: @deceze Would you agree, though, that if `assertEqual` is called within a loop (which is not uncommon) then the version in the question (problematic as it is) prints out the iteration without adding more LOCs? OH, BTW - regarding your question, then no - I'm not referring to a case where exceptions are raised as some sort of "return value".

Comment: @Ami 1) If you call it in a loop, all values in the loop should yield the same result: either success or an expected failure. The expected result shouldn't change halfway through the loop. Remember: you're always writing tests for the *expected* outcome; you tell unittest what you *expect*, and it alerts you to cases where that expectation fails. 2) If you write it in a loop, there isn't a lot of LOC overhead; you can cover 20 calls to your function with the same `try..catch` statement; so I don't see the big problem.

Comment: @Ami If anything, I'd suggest you write your own wrapper like `self.assertEqualsAndCatch(foo, i, msg=...)`. I.e.: pass a callback and its arguments, instead of a string to `eval`.

Comment: @deceze OK, many thanks, esp. for the last comment - that makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @deceze If you'd care to write your last comment in the answer, I'd be happy to accept it (not that you really need the rep, but still - I think it's a valuable answer.)

Comment: @Ami Agreed, that's a useful addition.

Comment: Just thought I'd say this was a great thread to follow. :) Wish there were more of these good conversations.

Comment: @ldjaw Thanks for your contribution as well, as well as snakecharmerb.