# Django Tests: increase testsRun counter

Tags: django, django-testing

In some Django Tests I have loop to test many things.
in the end-result it shows up as:

`Ran 1 test in 3.456s`

I would like to increment that counter for each loop, how can I do that?
It is using `subTest()` , but that does not update the counter (which I believe is a parameter `testsRun`)

my test looks something like this

```
class MyTestCase(TestCase):

   def test_auth_pages(self):
      pages = ['homepage', 'dashboard', 'profile']

      for page in pages:
         with self.subTest():
            # ....testsRun  += 1 
            self.c.login(username='test', password='test')
            response = self.c.get(reverse_lazy(page))
            self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code, msg=page)
            self.c.logout()
            response = self.c.get(reverse_lazy(page))
            self.assertEqual(302, response.status_code, msg=page)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you generate dynamic (parameterized) unit tests in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/how-do-you-generate-dynamic-parameterized-unit-tests-in-python)

Comment: @BearBrown no, it is working fine and it is using `self.subTest()` aleady. I just want to increment the counter.

Comment: by the answer you should get `Ran 3 tests in 0.006s` i will test it on my local machine or may be i not understand you

Comment: Why not just write three tests? If you need to run a large number of test you could always just write a script that writes your tests.py for you.

Comment: @RedCricket I simplified the code a bit, and it is actually about 40 and will be more later on. A script that generates code can be hard to maintain, since it needs to re-generate after every change.

Comment: it doesn't matter how many test are run, `test coverage` is important

Comment: Surely you can set the test counter to whatever you want to, e.g. `self._outcome.result.testsRun += len(pages)` (you can even introduce your own context manager `countedSubTest` or whatever for that matter), but why? Subtests are no separate tests entities and are not treated as such anywhere; it's just a tool not to stop the test on failure.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind changing testing framework, consider [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) with `pytest-django` package. You can easily parametrize a test using `@pytest.mark.parametrize`:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("page_name", ['homepage', 'dashboard', 'profile'])
def test_some_page(page_name, client):
    client.login(username='test', password='test')
    response = client.get(reverse_lazy(page))
    assert response.status_code == 200
    client.logout()
    response = client.get(reverse_lazy(page))
    assert response.status_code == 302
```

If not, you could create a test function factory that would accept the page name and return a test function for that page:

```py
class MyTestCase(TestCase):

   def _create_page_test(page_name):
       def test_function(self):
           self.c.login(username='test', password='test')
           response = self.c.get(reverse_lazy(page_name))
           self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code, msg=page_name)
           self.c.logout()
           response = self.c.get(reverse_lazy(page_name))
           self.assertEqual(302, response.status_code, msg=page_name)
        return test_function

    test_homepage = _create_page_test("homepage")
    test_dashboard = _create_page_test("dashboard")
    test_profile = _create_page_test("profile")
```

The added benefit of such changes is that each page has a separate test, independent from the other. That makes debugging easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a different test suite.

Check out [test generators](https://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators) from the [django-nose](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose) package

```py
def test_evens():
    for i in range(0, 5):
        yield check_even, i, i*3   # this generates 5 different tests

def check_even(n, nn):
    assert n % 2 == 0 or nn % 2 == 0
```