# Mock patch with several exceptions in side_effects

Tags: python, python-mock

When mocking objects, there are some instruments, which allow to change the result of a function.

Let's say, there is some class:

```
class Worker:

    def do_work(self):
        return perform_operation()
```

And I want to test some cases, when `do_work()` raises several exceptions in different situations:

```
@patch(
    'my.package.Worker.do_work',
    Mock(side_effect=[exc.VeryBadError, exc.NotThatBadError]
))
def test_worker_raise_errors():
    worker_user.call_worker()
```

But there is no way to pass several errors to `side_effects` like above, it would run only once and Fail only for `exc.VeryBadError`.

When I want to find a way to launch `test_worker_raise_errors()` twice for each exception, but w/o creating each test function per exception.

Is there a way to launch one test several times for each exception as a side effect and to see 2 Fails in this case?

Comment: This can be done as some sort of a parameterized test. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/how-do-you-generate-dynamic-parameterized-unit-tests-in-python

Answer (score 1):

This simple example will give you the hint:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

mock = Mock(
    side_effect=[
        AssertionError('Error 1'), 
        AttributeError('Error 2'),
    ]
)

try:
    mock()
except AssertionError as e:     # Catch the exception so that the execution can continue and we can test further.
    print(e)

try:
    mock()
except AttributeError as e:     # Catch the exception so that the execution can continue and we can test further.
    print(e)
```

Output:

```
Error 1
Error 2
```

---

You can use [self.assertRaises(...)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises) to make it a little bit cleaner.

Comment: Understood, but Is there any way to make a function be called twice, instead of calling a mocked instance twice explicitly? E.g.: I want to check it for 5 different exceptions, but don't want to call tested code 5 times.

Comment: Suppose you mock `do_work` like this (side_effect=[exc.VeryBadError, exc.NotThatBadError]), then `worker_user.call_worker()` will start execution and when it calls `do_work` for the first time it will raise `exc.VeryBadError` and when it calls `do_work` for the second time it will raise `exc.NotThatBadError`. I think this is what you want.