# Using a config/json file to generate tests in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

I'm working on building a test suite in Python using `unittest` for a small project and I'm building a bunch of tests to use different switches. The code for the tests is very reusable, and it would be a waste to keep copying the test over and modifying a single switch, the way I'm doing it below:

```
def get_some_data():
    return "randomtest"

def test1(self):
    config = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:get_some_data()}
    run_some_command(config)

def test2(self):
    config = {a:4, b:5, c:3, d:get_some_data()}
    run_some_command(config)
...
```

Is there a way for me to read a config file that contains all these configurations and run each configuration as an **individual** test? I know that if I have a single test read the config and run each config, any one of the configs failing will mean the test failing as a whole. I'm trying to avoid that.

The idea is to have the config file look something like:

```
[
{a:1,b:2,c:3,d:"randomtest"},
{a:4,b:5,c:3,d:"randomtest"},
...
]
```

I'm also open to reasonable suggestions on what alternatives I can explore over `unittest`

Answer (score 0):

With `pytest` you can [parametrize](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids) tests using the [`parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html) decorator, so you could do the following:

```
test_data = [
    {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 'randomtest'},
    {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 3, 'd': 'randomtest'},
]

@pytest.mark.parametrize('config', test_data)
def test(config):
    ...
```

With `unittest` you can use [`subTest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.subTest):

```
def test(self):
    for config in test_data:
        with self.subTest(config=config):
            ...  # do the actual test with `config` here
```

Comment: The `subTest` method seemed to do a lot of what I need without having to refactor the code for pytest. Unfortunately, I lose all benefits of the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` methods with this. Is there a way to force-invoke the methods for each subtest?

Comment: @vp199090 - you may also check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/how-do-you-generate-dynamic-parameterized-unit-tests-in-python) which shows some other possibilities in the answers.

Comment: If you want to use `setUp` and `tearDown` methods you need a separate test function for each case. This can be done by adding test functions dynamically based on the test data. I'll link the other question, if that solves your problem you can mark as duplicate.