# Python unit testing multiple inputs

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, multiple-input

This is a generic question geared towards unit testing specifically in Python. Is it acceptable to place 20 or some number of inputs to test in a dictionary as keys, where the values are the expected result output from the function?

I can't find an answer after scouring the internet. Almost everything I read were toy examples like adding numbers to obtain a sum or concatenating a first and last name. The following is another toyish example to describe my question in a simple way.

```
import unittest
import some_module

class SomeModuleUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_some_function(self):

        input_output_dict = {
            1: 1,
            2: 4,
            3: 9,
            4: 16,
            5: 25,
            6: 36,
            7: 49,
              .
              .
              .

            20: 400
        }

        for input_case, output_expected in input_output_dict.items():
            output_actual = some_module.some_function(input_case)
            self.assertEqual(output_expected, output_actual)
```

If this is considered archaic, what would be the Pythonic solution for testing multiple inputs?

Comment: People who down vote could at least share why you do so. I spent over an hour searching for an answer on this in order to follow best practices and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: As for the down vote - I would guess the question is seen as opinion - based and therefore not suitable for SO. As for your question - does the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/how-do-you-generate-dynamic-parameterized-unit-tests-in-python) help you? Also, you may consider pytest, where parametrization is built in.

Comment: Thanks for the link, that does provide some clarity to my question. I don't see how asking my question is opinionated but I too thought that may be why it was down voted. I asked if what I was doing is Pythonic which I presume an experienced Python developer would know the answer, yes or no. If yes great, if no then what is best practice. There are a lot of questions like this that get up voted, for example the link you included.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I will have a go. Trying to answer the explicit and implicit questions that I see here.

*Is it pythonic?*
If that is the data you have, then putting it in a dictionary is certainly ok. If it gets very large, you could consider reading it from a file, but this is probably not needed in this case.

*Is this the best way to test multiple inputs?*.
No, there are possibilities to [use test parametrization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/how-do-you-generate-dynamic-parameterized-unit-tests-in-python) in test frameworks that provide output that is better organized than in your example. The most commonly used is probably the  [`pytest.mark.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions) decorator in pytest.

*Do you need that much different input in your test?*
That depends on your functionality. If each of the inputs represents a different scenario, certainly yes. If they represent the same scenario, you may think of typical and edge cases, but usually you won't need many different inputs.