# How pass parameter to uniittest class in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, testcase

I want to pass some parameters to my unittest class.

```
class test_login(unittest.TestCase):
   
    def setUpClass(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote(ip)
```

How can I call TestCase class, each time with one of the IP in my server_ip list

```
server_ip = [ 'ip1' , 'ip2' ]
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use `setUpClass` for instance state?

Comment: my testcase class has two function (def test_login(self) and def test_logout(self)  ). I use setupClass to set IP. actually, I want to test Login and Logout into the two webservers.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/how-do-you-generate-dynamic-parameterized-unit-tests-in-python)