# Is there a way of running the same python test with different inputs

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Is there a way of running the same python test with multiple inputs? Ideally using unittest, but open to other libraries if not.

I'd like to be able to write something along the lines of

```
@inputs(1,2,3)
@inputs(4,5,9)
def test_my_test(self, a, b, c):
    self.assertEqual(a + b, c)
```

Comment: `unittest` itself doesn't provide something like this, but `pytest` does, and I've used the [`ddt` module](https://pypi.org/project/ddt/) in the past with `unittest`.

Comment: @chepner`ddt` provides exactly what I'm looking for. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you generate dynamic (parameterized) unit tests in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/how-do-you-generate-dynamic-parameterized-unit-tests-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Since Python 3.4, the [`subTest` context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#distinguishing-test-iterations-using-subtests) provides a similar functionality:

```
import unittest


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_test(self):
        inputs = [
            (1,2,3),
            (4,5,9),
        ]
        for a, b, c in inputs:
            with self.subTest(a=a, b=b, c=c):
                self.assertEqual(a + b, c)
```