# for loop in django unittest

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-views, django-testing, django-tests

I want to test register view in django project,

so I build some fake test cases(`self.correct_samples`)

after register successfully, it should redirect to home page which means the status code should be 302.

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls.base import reverse


class RegisterTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        url = reverse('account:register')
        self.response = self.client.get(url)

        self.correct_samples = (
            ('testuser1@email.com', 'testuser', 'test112233', 'test112233'),
            ('fakeuser@email.com', 'fake123', 'fakeuser111', 'fakeuser111'),
            ('correct@email.com', 'Jack', 'myfavorite', 'myfavorite'),

            ('failemail', 'Jack', 'myfavorite', 'myfavorite'),  # fail for purpose
        )

    def test_register_form(self):

        for test_case in self.correct_samples:

            email, username, password1, password2 = test_case
            self.response = self.client.post(reverse('account:register'), data={
                'email': email,
                'username': username,
                'password1': password1,
                'password2': password2,
            })

            self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 302)
            self.assertRedirects(
                self.response, expected_url='/', status_code=302, target_status_code=200)
```

The fourth data in `self.correct_samples` which is `('failemail', 'Jack', 'myfavorite', 'myfavorite')` should be a fail case.

but after `python manage.py test`. It passed.

```
(env) C:\Users\User\myblog>python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
C:\Users\User\myblog\env\lib\site-packages\whitenoise\base.py:115: UserWarning: No directory at: C:\Users\User\myblog\staticfiles\
  warnings.warn(u"No directory at: {}".format(root))
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.195s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

---

Here comes the tricky thing,

it failed after switching order from fourth to first.

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls.base import reverse


class RegisterTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        ...

        self.correct_samples = (
            ('failemail', 'Jack', 'myfavorite', 'myfavorite'),  # fail for purpose

            ('testuser1@email.com', 'testuser', 'test112233', 'test112233'),
            ('fakeuser@email.com', 'fake123', 'fakeuser111', 'fakeuser111'),
            ('correct@email.com', 'Jack', 'myfavorite', 'myfavorite'),
        )

    def test_register_form(self):
        ...
```

result:

```
(env) C:\Users\User\myblog>python manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
C:\Users\User\myblog\env\lib\site-packages\whitenoise\base.py:115: UserWarning: No directory at: C:\Users\User\myblog\staticfiles\
  warnings.warn(u"No directory at: {}".format(root))
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_register_form (account.tests.RegisterTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\myblog\account\tests.py", line 34, in test_register_form
    self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 302)
AssertionError: 200 != 302

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.026s

FAILED (failures=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

## **Why this happened?**

I have searched for related keywords like `unittest in forloop`, `multiple testcases in forloop`.

but it seems no answers for it, or maybe search through other keywords?

or something I missed or misunderstood?

thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Problem has been solved!

According to this questions [How do you generate dynamic (parameterized) unit tests in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899/how-do-you-generate-dynamic-parameterized-unit-tests-in-python/32939#32939)

#### Solution: parameterized